# Having trouble reproducing Wordpress 4.2 Persistent XSS vulnerability

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to reproduce a Wordpress persistent XSS vulnerability demonstrated on [this site](http://klikki.fi/adv/wordpress2.html) but I've been getting strange behavior. Nothing happens when I create a comment with the code from the site I linked. However, if I omit the '=' after "title", then the alert immediate pops up, even though the expected behavior is for the popup to appear when the mouse hovers over the comment. Also, the entire page is filled with 'A's. More importantly, when I look at 'View Source', the long string of A's isn't truncated as expected. I see all 64K of the A's I inserted, plus the ending tag.

I have no idea if it's a problem with my installation or a problem with the Javascript/HTML. I've installed Wordpress 4.2-RC1, MySQL 5.5.43, and PHP 5.3.25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working. Apparently it does matter whether you are posting as the admin of the account or as a guest. Also, I might have made a mistake inputting the PoC code in the comment box...